# LARGE zypper dup → Root partition full → (Heaven knows) I'm miserable now

Tags: upgrade, disk, suse

Suse Tumbleweed attempted a mega update of the system (~6000 packages at once) and filled the root filesystem, that, according to the installer recommendations, was 35 Gb.

I attempted ① to delete the cache of RPM files, but zypper/rpm notified me that it needed to create some temporary files on the root partition and failed, ② uninstall a largish package that has no reverse dependencies (Zoom) but rpm notified me that it needed to create some temporary files on the root partition and failed, ③ I used `btrfs file system resize +5G /` but I was told `ERROR: unable to resize '/': no enough free space` ④ so I shrinked the `/home` partition by 20Gb and tried again, same problem.

This is from `df`

```
localhost:~ # df /
Filesystem               1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-root   36700160 32168820         0 100% /
```

… from the above it looks like there are 4531340 1K blocks free (≈ 4.5Gb) and while I understand that a filesystem needs some elbow space …

I am really tempted to copy my user files to an USB key and install Debian, because `apt` duly informed me of problems with disk space every single time I tried to shoot myself in the foot, but I'd rather wait for an informed suggestion on my next course of action.

---

<strike>E.g., that bunch of `/.snapshots/xyz` directories, looks a promising target for a `rm -fr …`</strike> but — I don't know, I really need some guidance!

PS *I have learnt something about `snapper` in the last hour, at least as much as I need to leave `/.snapshots` alone until an expert unveils to me a different perspective.*

---

This is the output of a more appropriate command,

```
localhost:/ # btrfs filesystem df /
Data, single: total=33.21GiB, used=28.92GiB
System, single: total=32.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=1.76GiB, used=1.69GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=73.45MiB, used=0.00B
```

again, there are more than 4 Gb of not used (available?) space and everything fails due to full disk.

---

I'd like to mention that I can boot Windows, if some Windows' tool supports manipulating BTR file systems that could help, couldn't it?

Comment: what about inodes: `$  df -i` ?

Comment: @andra I'm told the filesystem has 0 inodes, that 0 inodes are used and 0 inodes are free. I guess these numbers derive from the fact that it's a BTRFS file system.

Comment: oh, sorry, I'm not of use with btrfs. But then one thing that catches my eye - is it ok with metadata?

Comment: maybe you have old snapshots you can remove ? if not check https://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-05-04_Fixing-Btrfs-Filesystem-Full-Problems.html maybe that can help you

Comment: You could go the manual route and check `du -xhd1 / | sort -h` to list directories that use a lot of space. Change the path to drill deeper.  Check folders that you think you do not need with `rpm --query --file` and maybe remove some folders or packages you do not need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have openSuSE tubleweed with small ssd - 80GB (will be replacing it in near future) so I totally understand your space issue.

The best way to update OpenSuse tumbleweed is:

`zypper ref && zypper dup --no-allow-vendor-change`

1. You need to check your images with [snapper](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Snapper_Tutorial)

---

`snapper` is really useful when things go south - it makes snapshots of your system.  I have to prune the snapshots regularly as I don't have enough space.  Here is how you do it.

To list current snapshots:

`sudo snapper ls`  which gives you a table with all the snapshots.  You can't delete the first one (root one, type single).  The subsequent you can delete based on its number.

To delete snapshots 2 to 11 do a:
`sudo snapper rm 2-11`

2. To disable *rpm* caching you can configure the `zypper`

---

`sudo zypper modifyrepo -K --all`

```
modifyrepo commands provide further options to tune the behavior per repository.

-K, --no-keep-packages
               Disable RPM files caching.
--all,  on all repositories
```